# XSS is working in my URL. How do I prevent it?

Tags: php, xss, javascript

My URL looks like this:

```
www.example.com/id?=15
```

My HTML is this part:

```
<form action="id?=$someidnum"> </form>
```

When I do this to my url:

```
www.example.com/id?=15"onclick="alert();"
```

and click on my page and the XSS code works.

I did research on XSS and was able to protect myself from text forms and such. However, how do I prevent it from coming from the URL?

I use PHP as my backend language.

Answer (score 4):

In exactly the same way as for all other inputs: rigorous input validation and correct escaping of input when it's echo'ed back.

To be somewhat educated, I think you should read the [OWASP top 10](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/). I see an enumeration vulnerability lurking right there with the presumably auto-incrementing ID

Answer (score 2):

> how do I prevent it coming from the url?

It doesn't matter what the source is. The sink matters.

In your case the sink is a double-quoted attribute. A user-supplied value can be printed securely in a double-quoted HTML attribute by HTML-escaping all double quotes. Hence, your snippet would be safe by replacing all occurences of `"` with `&quot;` in the variable `$someidnum`.

In PHP you can simply pass the variable through [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://secure.php.net/htmlspecialchars) which by default encodes `<`, `>`, `&` and `"`.

Answer (score 1):

Preventing XSS is done in the server side. There are plenty of built in functions in PHP to filter variables against XSS, one of them is `htmlentities()`.

Also avoid putting up variables in `action=""` in forms.
one way you can do that is:

```
<form action="#"> </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to sanitize all external source variables before using them in your php script:

1. $_SERVER
2. $_POST
3. $_GET
4. $_COOKIE
5. $_REQUEST (commonly not used)
6. Data taken from databases
7. APIs
8. Input data from the clients
9. $argv
10. php://stdin
11. php://input

All of the above can be resources that ill-intentioned can use to inject malicious data into your script.

After sanitizing input, then validate the ones which you need, then escape output.

Use CSRF protection in forms, especially login and register forms.

CSRF protection libraries are available in [OWASP](https://github.com/mebjas/CSRF-Protector-PHP)

If you need a library for sanitizing html code, then use [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org).

And if you need another library for sanitizing all types of user input, then you can use this [PHP Sanitizers library](https://github.com/PuneetGopinath/Sanitizers).

Comment: "Please wait for my ..." -- why not just add it when it's ready